# ODBC data source connection/PHP

Tags: php, sql, database, odbc

I'm trying to connect a DataSource to a PHP Page, using ODBC.
Here is my php page :

```
echo "Create the connection... <br /> <br />";
$connection = odbc_connect('SQLServer', '', '');

echo "Test the connection ...<br />";
if($connection){
  echo "Yep, we are live! Carry on!";
}

$query = <<<EOF
SELECT TOP 1000 [id]
  ,[name]
FROM [testdatabase].[dbo].[test3]
EOF;

$rs = odbc_exec($connection, $query);

odbc_result_all($rs, "cellpadding='3
background-color='d3d3d3'");
```

This is my DataSource : 
(https://gyazo.com/1945b1e18d4c40866538d07c75cec4c9)
(https://gyazo.com/d507d5f7bd856e0a564707bc93d2ce42)

When I go to WAMP in my php page I got this error:
(https://gyazo.com/2a579f501115d993bc3c267694b00ff7)

What's the problem ? I can't get this to work.
Thanks.

Database on MS SQL :

[image: Database]

Answer (score 0):

Try to create your odbc entry as system not as a user dsn.